# Ruby on Rails novice, how to redirect site to image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For you Ruby on Rails fans, this might be a very simple question.  I have been handed control of a RR site (none on our team handle RR), which is in the middle of being completely rebuilt with PHP.  In the mean time, the client has requested that the existing site display only an image, nothing more.

- The image would be hosted within the "public" folder within the RR framework.
- They want the entire site to become an un-clickable image.

What is the easiest way to do this? What would the code look like and where do I put that code?

I have attempted to change the routing code, but that has had no effect. I didn't even break the website.

I would appreciate any RR help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app/views/layouts/application.html.haml do this:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

Then in your terminal type `rails g controller Pages index`

Then go to app/views/pages/index.html.haml and put this

```
   = image_tag "/images/image.jpg", class: '', alt: ''
```

You can remove width, class and alt if you don't need it. And you need to put your image inside app/images/

Now go to your **routes.rb** and put this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'pages#index'
end
```

Comment: I will give this a try. There is no simpler way? Sorry, I am from the PHP world.

Comment: Hmm no not really, RoR is an MVC framework where the controller, views and routes are absolutely necessary in order to display something.

Comment: Let me know if you need any more assistence and/or if it worked.

Comment: @lussimo Sorry for the slow replies. The original developer that wrote the code used .haml instead of .html.erb.  Does that make any difference on how things need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply create an `index.html` file with the contents you desire in your `public` directory.